# How check current date is greater than end date?

Tags: asp-classic

In my asp page, i write code like this for checking date validation

```
<%
'Session 1
session.lcid=2057
Session("CheckIn")= "26/12/2009"
d=0
response.write session("CheckIn")&"----"&DateAdd("d",d,Session("CheckIn")) &"<br/>"

if session("CheckIn")= DateAdd("d",d,Session("CheckIn")) then
response.write "Session 1 is workings"
end if

'Session 2
a ="26/12/2009"
b ="26/12/2009"
if a=b then
response.write "Session 2 is workings"
end if
%>
```

In the **session 1**  "if" condition is not working.
But if i write date in string format in **session 2**, "IF" condition is working.

How i check "IF" condition in **Session 1** in my classic asp page

hoping your response,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hai Alex,

Use CDate function,

```
if CDate(a) > Cdate(b) then

 '.........

end if
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, `DateAdd("d", d, Session("CheckIn"))`, the session value is implicitly converted to a DateTime data type, and so the DateAdd succeeds. However, to then compare to the session variable, I suspect it is being converted implicitly to a string using whatever the default format is (unlikely to be dd/mm/yyyy).

You need to make sure that the two values you are comparing are of the same type. I'd suggest:

```
if CDate(session("CheckIn")) = DateAdd("d",d,Session("CheckIn")) then
```

for your first check